# Razor Page Control Events

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

I have several select lists in my .cshtml view page populated successfully from SQL Server. After a selection is made in the Payee list, I want to perform some additional database work based on the PayeeID. I can handle the SQL and C# coding, I just can't figure out how to get the PayeeID back into the code behind file.
I know I can go from Model to View, but how do I do it the other way around?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass `PayeeID` from view to handler,here is a demo(Set `PayeeID` as values of options,.net core will bind data with `name` attribute,such as `name="Payee"`):

```
<form method="post" asp-page-handler="PassPayeeId">
    <select id="Payee" name="Payee">
        <option value="1">Payee1</option>
        <option value="2">Payee2</option>
        <option value="3">Payee3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

handler:

```
public IActionResult OnPostPassPayeeId(string Payee)
        {
            return Page();
        }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Yiyi, Thank you for this answer.. I see the concept. I'll mark this as answered, but my form contains several lists and I need the program to react to "After Update" type events. My actual scenario is a data entry form, and after a payee selection, I will take that PayeeID and find the last payment made to that PayeeID, and populate other controls. Easily done in JS, node, C#, but I've yet to find a good implementation in Razor Pages. Even if I use ajax within the razor page, I still need to get the PayeeID back to the code behind.